# What design pattern is used in a ORM?

Tags: design-patterns, orm

Is a ORM a Design Pattern or does it *uses* Design Patterns? If it uses, which is? I just found on WikiPedia one DP (DAO).

I'm a bit confused cause some articles say that ORM is a DP and others that it's not - and no one say witch DP it uses.

[ORM Offensive Anti Pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/orm-offensive-anti-pattern)

[ORM - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)

Comment: Data-Access-Object is a lot less broad than ORM. A DAO is a single class. An ORM implementation is a very large and complicated codebase where different parts of the code use all kinds of patterns. They are not comparable. Maybe see Martin Fowler’s patterns of enterprise architecture book.

Comment: You may find this relevant: [ORM Is an Offensive Anti-Pattern](https://www.yegor256.com/2014/12/01/orm-offensive-anti-pattern.html)

Answer (score 5):

### Design Patterns

> In software engineering, a software design pattern is a general reusable solution to a **commonly occurring problem** within a given context in software design.

**Source**: [Wikipedia Design Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern)

### ORM

ORM is a technique for solving the **commonly occurring problem** of converting data between incompatible type systems and objects in OOP languages.

### Conclusion

**ORM** is definitely a **Design Pattern** used to solve a commonly occurring Software Engineering problem.